# How to get the current timestamp in other timezones in Golang?

Tags: go, timestamp, timezone

I need to get the current time in different time-zones.

Currently I know that we can do the following:

```
t := time.Now()
fmt.Println("Location:", t.Location(), ":Time:", t)
utc, err := time.LoadLocation("America/New_York")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("err: ", err.Error())
}
fmt.Println("Location:", utc, ":Time:", t.In(utc))
```

The LoadLocation name is taken to be a location name corresponding to a file in the IANA Time Zone database, such as "America/New_York".

Is there a simpler way to get the current time, if the country name, or the GMT offset is given e.g +530 for India?

Edit: I would also want to support Day light savings.

Comment: While there are some cases where using a fixed offset is appropriate, generally it's better to use the `Continent/City`. Time zones and daylight savings rules are political and change. Using `Continent/City` will allow your application to adjust to those changes as the underlying IANA Time Zone database is updated. It will also take care of daylight savings for you.

Answer (score 126):

```
//init the loc
loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Shanghai")

//set timezone,  
now := time.Now().In(loc)
```

Comment: I assume you mean

    now := time.Now().In(loc)

Comment: The location timezone information is picked up from the system and there is a chance that it will not find the location string. If the location is not found your binary will crash, so make sure you handle this error.

Answer (score 18):

No, that is the best way. You can create your custom `Location` using [FixedZone](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#FixedZone) and use that custom  location.

> FixedZone returns a Location that always uses the given zone name and
>   offset (seconds east of UTC).

Comment: Thanks Fabrizio! I also want to support daylight savings. Any pointers on that?

Comment: I don't know about defining custom daylight saving settings, but the Time Zones from the database already support daylight saving.

Answer (score 5):

I like [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42136791/9935654)

```golang
//init the loc
loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Shanghai")

//set timezone,  
now := time.Now().In(loc)
```

Where can I find the name of the location?

> You can see it on the [zoneinfo.zip](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/99fa49e/lib/time)

some example

```golang
package _test

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func TestTime(t *testing.T) {
    myT := time.Date(2022, 4, 28, 14, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    for _, d := range []struct {
        name     string
        expected string
    }{
        {"UTC", "2022-04-28 14:00:00 +0000 UTC"},
        {"America/Los_Angeles", "2022-04-28 07:00:00 -0700 PDT"},
        {"Asia/Tokyo", "2022-04-28 23:00:00 +0900 JST"},
        {"Asia/Taipei", "2022-04-28 22:00:00 +0800 CST"},
        {"Asia/Hong_Kong", "2022-04-28 22:00:00 +0800 HKT"},
        {"Asia/Shanghai", "2022-04-28 22:00:00 +0800 CST"},
    } {
        loc, _ := time.LoadLocation(d.name)
        if val := fmt.Sprintf("%s", myT.In(loc)); val != d.expected {
            fmt.Println(val)
            t.FailNow()
        }
    }
}
```

<kbd>[go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Zo5qt6sVNAK)</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

Something not mentioned here is how to switch a `time.Time` value from one location or timezone to another location or timezone. Here's how I did it:

```
time.Local = time.UTC // default to UTC for all time values

func California() *time.Location {
    la, err := time.LoadLocation("America/Los_Angeles")
    if err != nil {
        panic("should not error on generating current time in la")
    }
    return la
}

func Chicago() *time.Location {
    chicago, err := time.LoadLocation("America/Chicago")
    if err != nil {
        panic("should not error on generating current time in chicago")
    }

    return chicago
}

caNow := time.Now().In(California()) // get Now in California
chiNow := time.Now().In(Chicago()) // get Now in Chicago

otherChiNow := caNow.In(Chicagio()) // convert CA time to CHI time
```